# Mysql8 xdevapi node.js CRUD table.select problems

Tags: mysql, node.js

let's see this select:

```
getSession(<connectionOptions>)
.then(s => { return s.getSchema('<schema>') } )
.then(s => { return s.getTable('<table>') } )
.then(t => t.select('*') // or .select('COUNT(*)')
.where('<where>')
.execute(row => myHandler(row, <other params>)));
//
function myHandler(row, <other params>) {
...
}
```

I have three questions and I haven't found anything after reading https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en and searching the internet:

1. How can I see and handle that a select has an empty result set? In the node.js xdevapi implementation I do not get the result set, only result rows one after another so I suppose my callback is not even once called.
2. Because my callback is called several times I do not know when it is called the last time i.e., when do I get the last row from the result set. How can I see and handle it?
3. COUNT(*) / * is not accepted in the select string throwing an unexpected token error at the * character both cases. This is standard SQL, though. I can see that I can use session.sql('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table') but I am curious to know why not in CRUD then?

Comment: The link you provided returns 'page not found'

Comment: sorry /en is added to the URL and it displays correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are working with promises, not callbacks. so adding `then` after the `execute` will let you know that the execution finished.
2. One option is: In the handler function you can push to external array or simple counter, based on your needs, when the `then` is called, you can refer to the counter to get the results. Second option - based on [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/devapi-users-working-with-relational-tables.html), it looks like the last `then` after the `execute` will resolve with all the results as array. so if you need to make action only after you get all the results, do not put anything inyour handler function, just add the `then` and do what you need there.
3. It looks like you need to use it as function, like `.then(t => t.count('*')` or `.then(t => t.select('*').count()`

P.S. I never used the xdevapi, it looks great. if you are using it only for relational operations I suggest you take a look at [knex](https://knexjs.org/)

Comment: 1. and 2. are resolved with the .then after .execute (see below the complete findings). Thanks.

Comment: 1. and 2. are resolved with the .then after .execute (see below the complete findings). 
For 3. I can use a workaround with the .then. Further t.count('*') works but it cannot have a .where clause.
Thanks.

Comment: Great! You are right, the code for `count` here https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-nodejs/blob/76a3b003a63e3eb91057324b664bb73cc2e3a930/lib/DevAPI/Table.js is just a simple query, with no use of the selectTable handler.

Comment: Some minor corrections/extensions to the original answer. Regarding points 1 and 2, `execute()` effectively returns a `Promise`, however it is not resolved with a reference to result set data, which means you need both the callback to process those data and the `then()` handler to know when it ends. Regarding point 3, you can use a literal like `select("COUNT('*')")`.

Answer (score 0):

For the records:

After .execute you can add a .then where you can access some useful info through functions (affected rows, generated IDs, warnings etc.) and of course you can catch the end of the execution:

`.execute()
.then(info => myInfoHandler(info,<other params>)
...
if (info.getAffectedRowsCount()==0) { //empty result set
}`

This way you do not need COUNT(*).